# How to add a ripple effect on a layout with rounded corners?

Tags: android, android-layout, rippledrawable

I want to set a ripple effect on layout with rounded corners. How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Answer (score -4):

just set these properties in xml file

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
```

That should do it.

Comment: This does not make the layout border corner round.

Comment: then try `android:foregroud="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" ` instead

Comment: @ChetanAshtivkar `android:foregroud="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" ` doesn't work either